# Rails 4 undefined public method for ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a clean Rails 4.0.2 and Ruby 2.0.0p353 project.

There exists an ActiveModel, *Foo*.

I've defined a public method called *bar* that outputs the string "Hello World"

When calling *Foo.bar* from the console, it raises the "NoMethodError undefined method 'bar' error."

I have checked the model is the ancestor of ActiveRecord::Base, which returns true

```
Foo.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
```

When checking if the method exists for the model, I get a return false

```
Foo.methods.include?(:bar)
```

I am dumbfounded as to why the method isn't being included. Any ideas? I have reloaded and restarted the console and made sure the code has been saved.

Comment: Without seeing any code we're guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you define the method? Please note that if you defined it as

```
class Foo
  def bar 
    "hello"
  end
end
```

then `bar` is an **instance method** of the `Foo` class and you can only invoke it on an instance of `Foo`, not on the class.

```
Foo.bar
# => NoMethodError
Foo.new.bar
# => "hello"
```

Vice-versa, in this case (note `self`)

```
class Foo
  def self.bar 
    "hello"
  end
end
```

you are defining a class method.

```
Foo.bar
# => "hello"
Foo.new.bar
# => NoMethodError
```

Comment: Oops, that was embarrassing. Totally forgot to define it as a class method -_-. Thanks for the reminder!